# How to Reference a Particular Node in a GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

I have a grid of tiles with a stack pane on top of each tile in order to place a shape on each tile.
 
I want to have a method by which I can remove the stack pane from a particular tile on the grid, which means that in effect it should remove the shape on top of the tile. 
Could I perhaps store each stack pane in an array of some sort and reference it by the index? I populate the grid by using a nested for loop. 
I am also given the row and column of the stack pane that I want to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a reference to each node, or retrieve a node dynamically by row - column index:

```
Node getChildByRowColumn(final GridPane gridPane, final int row, final int col){

    for(final Node node : gridPane.getChildren()){
        if (GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == null) continue ; //ignore Group 
        if(GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row && GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == col) return node;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks a ton!!